# How to change header section based on url query param in reactjs

Tags: react-redux

I have developed web app using ReactJS when i navigate one page to another page the header text should be changed based url (i created header component and i did import in all pages) how to achieve this

Comment: Post your code/relevant snippets and explain the issue more clearly. What have you tried? What were the results? Are you using `react-router` or snooping the URL manually?

Comment: i have header component where it has toggle menu (three line icon for open side menu )at left side and notification button button at right side . same header am using in all pages . but in some pages i have to show back button and in header page's title  rather than showing toggle menu at left side . based on URL have to change header icon and title dynamically  i am trying with ract router for navigate  linke this <Link to ={path:"xxxx"} />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using client-side use javascript to handle it:

```
componentDidUpdate(){
 var path= window.location.pathname; // lets imaging that url is "/home/x"
 var pathArray = path.split( '/' );
 var loc= pathArray[2];//number of part of url that is changing, here it rerurns x
 if(loc === "product"){ // if x be "product" it returns true
  //do somting
 }
}
```

if using server-side rendering instead of using "var path= window.location.pathname;" it's better to save URL path in store and use it in your component.

Comment: but its not working inside componentDidUpdate() its working inside of componentDidMount()

Comment: @Ramusesan Sorry, I forgot to describe it. It depends on how are you handling your pages. if both pages are using one parent component it must be inside componentDidUpdate and if they are using different components for each page it should be placed in componentDidMount.

Comment: i see great explaination